# Including multiple static libraries in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am trying to incorporate the three20 library and Keith Lazuka's Kal (Calendar UI) library into my project. I have included the three20 static library and everything works fine.

Now when I try to add Kal into to my project using the instruction specified in here https://github.com/klazuka/Kal, Xcode is unable to find the header files and I get an error:

Kal.h:No such file or directory

However if I have a new project and I add the Kal library, it works fine. So do I have to do something special to include two static libraries in my xcode project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may still need to tell XCode where to find the header files for the kal.h library.

- Go to Project->Edit Project Settings.
- Select the "build" tab. Scroll down to the Search Paths.
- **Double clicking User Header Search Paths brings a dialog box. NOTE: In Xcode 4 I found that you actually need to add the path to "Header Search Path" NOT "User Header Search Path"
- Drag directories from Finder into the dialog box or click the + button to add manually.

** I've not really gotten the hang of xcode yet so Im putting the same search paths in Framework, Header and User Header. So far it's worked out fine, but I shall expect (and deserve) a scolding from the xcode savvy individuals for such behavior.

Comment: Actually I has to edit the project settings as well as the Active target for it to work. Finally got it to work. I hope that is a correct solution.